# Outlook/Exchange - how to programmatically export users in distribution list?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, exchange-server, office-automation

How do I export all of the names and email addresses from a distribution list in Outlook using code? I have access to an Outlook 2000 or Outlook 2007 client. Ideally I would like the code to be in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you asked about c#, but the following script from  http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/officetips/may05/tips0524.mspx may be of some use.

```
Const olFolderContacts = 10

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set colContacts = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items
intCount = colContacts.Count

For i = 1 To intCount
    If TypeName(colContacts.Item(i)) = "DistListItem" Then
        Set objDistList = colContacts.Item(i)
        Wscript.Echo objDistList.DLName
        For j = 1 To objDistList.MemberCount
    Wscript.Echo objDistList.GetMember(j).Name & " -- " & _
               objDistList.GetMember(j).Address
        Next 
        Wscript.Echo
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

use outlook component model
http://www.dotnetjunkies.ddj.com/Tutorial/2E1EEEAF-C78A-4A38-A830-AC204B12DF83.dcik

Comment: Do you have specific information on how to use the object model to access the distribution list?